# How do I close live chat window without cross using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the reviews from this page https://everdeskplus.com/products/everdesk-max but I am stuck with this error. I need it to click the '>' button until it reaches the last page. It does not allow me to click the '>' button and said that it cannot be found.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://everdeskplus.com/products/everdesk-max")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# Close Spin pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='pge_HN8znV-LA']/div[1]/span"))).click()


# Switch to Iframe and close the chat box
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"chat-button")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@id='gorgias-chat-messenger-button']"))).click()

#Switch back to the default content
driver.switch_to.default_content()

# Scroll to the footer and click on "Next" page button 
footer = driver.find_element_by_class_name("stamped-pagination stamped-reviews-ul")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",footer)
nextbutton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"'//*[@id='stamped-reviews-tab']/ul/li[14]/a'")))
nextbutton.click()
```

This is the error I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-de1d77662195> in <module>
     21 
     22 # Scroll to the footer and click on "Next" page button
---> 23 footer = driver.find_element_by_class_name("stamped-pagination stamped-reviews-ul")
     24 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",footer)
     25 nextbutton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"'//*[@id='stamped-reviews-tab']/ul/li[14]/a'")))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_class_name(self, name)
    562             element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('foo')
    563         """
--> 564         return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
    565 
    566     def find_elements_by_class_name(self, name):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    974                 by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    975                 value = '[name="%s"]' % value
--> 976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
    978             'value': value})['value']

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".stamped-pagination stamped-reviews-ul"}
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.54)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below and confirm:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://everdeskplus.com/products/everdesk-max")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# Close Spin pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='pge_HN8znV-LA']/div[1]/span"))).click()

# Switch to Iframe and close the chat box
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"chat-button")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@id='gorgias-chat-messenger-button']"))).click()

#Switch back to the default content
driver.switch_to.default_content()

# Scroll to the footer and click on "Next"
footer = driver.find_element_by_id("vpc-configure-footer")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",footer)
nextbutton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='vpc-sticky-next-btn']")))
nextbutton.click()
```

**Update:**
Replace below code:

```
# Scroll to the footer and click on "Next" page button 
footer = driver.find_element_by_class_name("stamped-pagination stamped-reviews-ul")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",footer)
nextbutton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"'//*[@id='stamped-reviews-tab']/ul/li[14]/a'")))
nextbutton.click()
```

with this

```
# Scroll to the footer and click on "Next" page button
nextbutton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@class='next']/a")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",nextbutton)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I got this error ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <iframe id="chat-button" title="Gorgias live chat messenger" class="gorgias-chat-key-sef6vt" srcdoc="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div class=&quot;frame-root&quot;></div></body></html>" cd_frame_id_="267007688a414fec39b6d1b7b7d663e5"></iframe> is not clickable at point (584, 496). Other element would receive the click: <div id="om-campaign-73" class="om-workspace-content" style="display: block; height: 100vh;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.54)

Comment: @Beaty -  The above code worked fine for me. Mention the line of code that throws this error.

Comment: its this line: wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@id='gorgias-chat-messenger-button']"))).click()

Comment: @Beaty - I tried again and it dint throw any exception. Make sure that spin pop-up is closed.

Comment: yes i did. can i know how to remove overlay? cause I think the div id="om-campaign-73" is the overlay that is blocking

Comment: i meant clicking the next page arrow for the product reviews

Comment: @Beaty - Update the question with the code you are trying.

Comment: i have updated the code

Comment: @Beaty - I have reupdated the answer. Go through the same.

Comment: i keep getting this error : Message: element click intercepted: Element <iframe id="chat-button" title="Gorgias live chat messenger" class="gorgias-chat-key-sef6vt" srcdoc="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div class=&quot;frame-root&quot;></div></body></html></iframe> is not clickable at point (584, 496). Other element would receive the click: <div id="om-campaign-73" class="om-workspace-content" style="display: block; height: 100vh;">...</div> at line wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@id='gorgias-chat-messenger-button']"))).click()

Comment: @Beaty - I get no such exception. The line works fine for me.